# how to replace string elements in nested list with number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I need to replace string elements in nested list with index number. For example if i have nested list:

```
x = ['a', 'b', ['c', ['d', 'e']], 'f']
```

I want to get:

```
[1, 2, [3, [4, 5]], 6]
```

i know the that i should make a recursive function and also use

```
isinstance()
```

this didn't work:

```
def indexer(f, lst):
    return [indexer(f, x) if isinstance(x, list) else x.index() for x in lst]
```

Comment: [not a python expert] `x.index()` only reads the value and calculates the index. you aren't storing the new index at all? Try `x=x.index()`?

Comment: Do you want to modify the list in place, or do you want a new list with the old list unaltered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using recursion.

**Ex:**

```
def get_index(lst, c=1):
    result = []
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            r, c = get_index(i, c)
            result.append(r)
        else:
            result.append(c)
            c += 1
    return result, c        

x = ['a', 'b', ['c', ['d', 'e']], 'f']
result, _ = get_index(x)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, [3, [4, 5]], 6]
```

Comment: and how could i get ['a', 'b', ['c', ['d', 'e']], 'f'] out of [1, 2, [3, [4, 5]], 6] again?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = ['a', 'b', ['c', ['d', 'e']], 'f']
def get_index(c):
    return ord(c) - ord('a') + 1
def get_reversed_index(i):
    return chr(i - 1 + ord('a'))
def indexer(lst):
    return [indexer(x) if isinstance(x, list) else get_index(x) for x in lst]
def reverse_indexer(lst):
    return [reverse_indexer(x) if isinstance(x, list) else get_reversed_index(x) for x in lst]

y = indexer(x)
z = reverse_indexer(y)
print(y)
print(z)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, [3, [4, 5]], 6]
['a', 'b', ['c', ['d', 'e']], 'f']
```

Comment: and how could i get ['a', 'b', ['c', ['d', 'e']], 'f'] out of [1, 2, [3, [4, 5]], 6] again?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```py
def list_to_index(old_list, starting_index = None):
    new_list = []
    index = starting_index if starting_index else 0
    for item in old_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            new_item = list_to_index(item, index)
            new_list.append(new_item[0])
            index = new_item[1]
        else:
            new_list.append(index + 1)
            index += 1
    return [new_list, index]



x = ['a', 'b', ['c', ['d', 'e']], 'f']
print(list_to_index(x)[0])

## Expected output
## [1, 2, [3, [4, 5]], 6]
```

Comment: and how could i get ['a', 'b', ['c', ['d', 'e']], 'f'] out of [1, 2, [3, [4, 5]], 6] again?

Answer (score 0):

With builtin `copy.deepcopy` and `itertools.count` *magic*:

(the input initial list is not *mutated*)

```
from itertools import count
from copy import deepcopy

def indexer(lst):
    counter = count(1)
    def _visit(lst):
        for i, v in enumerate(lst):
            if isinstance(v, list):
                _visit(v)
            else:
                lst[i] = next(counter)
        return lst
    return _visit(deepcopy(lst))

x = ['a', 'b', ['c', ['d', 'e']], 'f']
print(indexer(x))
```

The output:

```
[1, 2, [3, [4, 5]], 6]
```

---

Another test case:

```
x = [['g', 'h'], 'a', [['i', 'k'], 'l'], ['m', 'p', ['o']], 'b', ['c', ['d', 'e']], 'f']
print(indexer(x))
```

The output:

```
[[1, 2], 3, [[4, 5], 6], [7, 8, [9]], 10, [11, [12, 13]], 14]
```

Comment: and how could i get ['a', 'b', ['c', ['d', 'e']], 'f'] out of [1, 2, [3, [4, 5]], 6] again?

Comment: That's another subject for another question. The current "question"/issue is solved: the initial list retained unchanged and the `indexer` gives the needed indices structure

Answer (score 0):

Shorter recursive solution with an iterator:

```
import itertools
c = itertools.count(1)
def to_int(d):
  return [to_int(i) if isinstance(i, list) else next(c) for i in d]


print(to_int(['a', 'b', ['c', ['d', 'e']], 'f']))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, [3, [4, 5]], 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cute recursive approach that allows you to map any function to a nested list, and then uses the `defaultdict` trick to index elements, assuming you want the same elements to be represented by the same index:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def map_nested(fnc, lst):
    if isinstance(lst, list):
        return [map_nested(fnc, sub) for sub in lst]
    return fnc(lst)

d = defaultdict(lambda: len(d))
map_nested(d.__getitem__, ['a', 'b', ['c', ['d', 'e']], 'f', 'a'])
# [0, 1, [2, [3, 4]], 5, 0]
```